# How to create a column that is a repetition of a column's contents by a specified number of times mentioned in another column?

Tags: sas

I want to use columns 'A' and 'B' to create column 'Result' which is content of A repeated B number of times

```
A  B  Result
z  3  zzz
az 2  azaz
```

Tried using `Result=repeat(A,B)` which didn't work out. Is there something I missed while using the repeat statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REPEAT function returns a character value consisting of the first argument repeated *n* times,  Thus, the first argument appears *n + 1* times in the result.

So, you have to subtract 1 from B to get the result that you want.

Try

```
Result=repeat(A,int(B)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple in R! . Sorry I did not look for the tag, but here is how R does it

Try the function makeNstr() from package Hmisc

```
>require(Hmisc)
>df <- data.frame(A = c("a","az"), B = c(3,2)) 
>Result <- makeNstr(df$A,df$B)
>df <- cbind(df,Result)
>df
 A B Result
1  a 3    aaa
2 az 2   azaz
```

Hope you find it useful